# Hierarchical attributes in XACML Policy

Tags: authorization, access-control, xacml, abac, wso2-identity-server

We are using WSO2 Identity Server 5.1.0 .

We have a location hierarchy like Plant1->Area1->unit1. Now if a user is having attribute for the Plant1, he should get access to unit1 as well (all children of the parent in a tree).

Can we specify this in XACML? We have the hierarchy stored in DB. We can provide the list of hierarchical elements as a list of attributes also if so required.

Problem explained in sample : 
A user bob has been given access to area2 as shown below :

Plant1

|--Area1

```
     |--Unit1
```

|--Area2

```
     |--Unit2
```

We want to specify the Area2 location in XACML policy. Now if the request with area2 or unit2 comes that should be permitted while if the request with plant1, area1 or unit1 comes that should get denied.

I need the structure for XACML policy.

Comment: Yes, you can there. There is an optional profile Axiomatics implements which does just that.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this with a custom PIP (Policy Information Point, aka Attribute Provider) in XACML implementations like [AuthzForce](https://github.com/authzforce/core). I don't know WSO2 IS as much but according to the doc, it is also extensible with [custom PIPs](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS5xx/Writing+a+Custom+Policy+Info+Point), so I assume this should do the trick.

The idea is that in the XACML Policy, you use an AttributeDesignator with a custom AttributeId to indicate that the top parent value in the hierarchy of some attribute is requested, e.g. AttributeId = *resource-id-parent* for the parent value of *resource-id* attribute value.

What your custom PIP does: when this custom attribute id *resource-id-parent* is requested, the PIP gets the value of the attribute *resource-id* from the request, i.e. "area2" or "unit2", then gets the corresponding top value in the hierarchy from your DB (or all the values above if you will) and return it as bag. Then, in the XACML Policy, you can use string-equal in a Match or string-at-least-one-member-of in a Condition to match the AttributeDesignator with "area2" (remember an AttributeDesignator always evaluate to a bag).